# Force use JsonPropertyName while saving into CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am working with an existing cosmos db. One of the properties in documents has pascal case naming (as below) whilst all the other properties have camel case naming.

```
Public class MyModel{
[JsonPropertyName("MyClass")]
public MyClass MyClass{ get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("transactionId")]
public string TransactionId { get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("id")]
public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have the below code to replace existing records which I fetch from the db based on some criteria.

```
private static async Task ReplaceMultipleAsync(List<Record> records)
        {
            List<Task> concurrentTasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                concurrentTasks.Add(_container.ReplaceItemAsync(record, record.Id, new PartitionKey(record.UserId)));
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(concurrentTasks);
        }
```

With this update, my existing documents gets overwritten and MyClass (pascal case) property becomes myclass (Camel case). I don't want this overwrite as we have a lot of records in our db and they are used by some reporting which would break if this is changed.

Creating cosmos client

```
private static void InitializeCosmosClientInstance(IConfigurationSection configurationSection)
        {
            IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                                                .Build();
            //var playerSection = configuration.GetSection(nameof(Player));

            _databaseName = configurationSection["DatabaseName"];
            _containerName = configurationSection["ContainerName"];
            var account = configurationSection["Account"];
            var key = configurationSection["Key"];
            var options = new CosmosClientOptions()
            {
                AllowBulkExecution = true,
                SerializerOptions = new CosmosSerializationOptions()
                {
                    PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
                }
            };
            _cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(account, key, options);
        }
```

Getting container instance

```
 _database = _cosmosClient.GetDatabase(_databaseName);
 _container = _database.GetContainer(_containerName);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code sets a camel case naming policy for serialization. If you don't want this, why this configuration?

Comment: If I remove it, I am getting a Bad Request error from Cosmos.

Comment: What does the rest of the model class look like? You need to ensure "id" is used for the built-in ID, even if other properties are PascalCase.

Comment: @NoahStahl Updated my model in my post. Thanks.